# How to find django objects in a manytomany relation (with a throught)?

Tags: django, django-models

I need to find services with pricing for each user. I've defined my models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """Default user model."""
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)    
    proposals = models.ManyToManyField(
        Service,
        through=Pricing,
        blank=True)


class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Pricing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

In my template, I can get my user with associated proposal with this for loop

```
{% for proposal in object.proposals.all %}
    {{ proposal }}
{% endfor %}
```

I do not have prices but only services names. What am i missing ?

Comment: Can you share the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets the `related_name` of the foreign key field:

```py
class Pricing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='pricing_instances') # Replace 'pricing_instances' with what makes sense to you
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

Then you can access `price` like this:

```py
{% for pricing_instance in object.pricing_instances.all %}
    {{ pricing_instance.price }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You enumerate over the `object.pricing_set.all()` with:

```
{% for pricing in object.pricing_set.all %}
    {{ pricing.service }}: {{ pricing.price }}
{% endfor %}
```

This will however result in an *N+1 problem*, by making use of a `Prefetch` object in the view, we can avoid that.

If you are for example fetching a `User` object, you can prefetch the `pricing`s and the related `service`s with:

```
User.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('pricing_set', Pricing.objects.select_related('service'))
)
```

If you thus make use of a single `User` with primary key `pk`, then this can be implemeted as:

```
object = User.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('pricing_set', Pricing.objects.select_related('service'))
).get(pk=some_pk)
```